# AngularJS Directive to loop through array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using AngularJS, I need to create a directive that loops through an array and displays the relevant information:

Here is my code so far but for some reason it is now working. 
Kindly help. What is being displayed is the text below as plain text. Obviously the images are not being loaded as well.

*info.title

 info.developer

 info.price | currency*

Here are the files used.

**appInfo.html** - *the template to be used by the directive for each element*

```
<img class="icon" ng-src="{{ info.icon }}"> 
<h2 class="title">{{ info.title }}</h2> 
<p class="developer">{{ info.developer }}</p> 
<p class="price">{{ info.price | currency }}</p>
```

**appInfo.js** - *directive*

```
app.directive('appInfo', function() { 
  return { 
    restrict: 'E', 
    scope: { 
      info: '=' 
    }, 
    templateUrl: 'appInfo.html' 
  }; 
});
```

**app.js** - *module*

```
var app = angular.module('AppMarketApp', []);
```

**controller** - *repeated elements to test*

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.apps =
    [ 
  { 
    icon: 'img/move.jpg', 
    title: 'MOVE', 
    developer: 'MOVE, Inc.', 
    price: 0.99 
  }, 
  { 
    icon: 'img/shutterbugg.jpg', 
    title: 'Shutterbugg', 
    developer: 'Chico Dusty', 
    price: 2.99 
  },
    { 
    icon: 'img/move.jpg', 
    title: 'MOVE', 
    developer: 'MOVE, Inc.', 
    price: 0.99 
  }, 
  { 
    icon: 'img/shutterbugg.jpg', 
    title: 'Shutterbugg', 
    developer: 'Chico Dusty', 
    price: 2.99 
  } 
];
}]);
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Include the AngularJS library -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="AppMarketApp">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>App Market</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="main" ng-controller="MainController">
      <div class="container">          

        <div class="card" ng-repeat="a in apps"> 
  <app-info info="{{a}}"></app-info>
        </div>   

      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Modules -->
    <script src="app.js"></script>

    <!-- Controllers -->
    <script src="MainController.js"></script>

    <!-- Directives -->
    <script src="appInfo.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: whats wrong with the ng-repeat directive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat="a in apps"> 
  <app-info info="a"></app-info>
        </div>
```

Attributes that already expect expressions don't need curly braces.